# Summarize table by group and add logic to keep data

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, dissolve, qgis-modeler, function

I need to dissolve a polygon layer by group but, at the same time, I need to keep some of the data in extra columns. This is the diagram:

[image]

This is the logic for the new group:

- Cod = "Cod" where N1 is the highest
- N1 = highest "N1" of group A
- N2 = highest "N2" of group A
- N3 = get value of N1 where "Cod" is the longest in length characters
- N4 = get value of N1 where "Cod" is different from 0 AND 1 AND 1_2

The issue here is that I need to incorporate this into the modeler. Do I have any possibility. By the way, I could use either QGIS 2.XX or 3.XX